# Remove legend if a plot in an array of plots is empty

Tags: plotting, regions, legending, inequalities

In an array of plots of regions (inequalities) `p[..]` which are eventually combined using `Show`, how do I suppress the legend of plots which are empty, and look like this

[image]

More generally, if in a given range of $x$ and $y$ over which a region is prescribed to be plotted, if `RegionPlot` does not find a solution (so that there is no region to shade or fill), is there a way to get a `True` or `False` value from RegionPlot corresponding to whether the region exists or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express the region using `ImplicitRegion` and then plot it or check the area of the region. Example:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
RegionPlot[reg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Chop@N@Area[reg]
```

> 9.91915

Checking to see if the area of the region is nonzero:

```
If[Chop@N@Area[reg] > 0, ...]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
colors = RotateLeft[ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2, 3}];
regs = {x^2 < (y - 2)^3 + 1, (y + 2)^2 < (x - 2)^3 + 1, x + y <= -2}; 

Show[With[{col = First[colors = RotateRight[colors]]}, 
    RegionPlot[#, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> col, 
     PlotLegends -> If[Area[ImplicitRegion[#, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}]] === 0, None, {#}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]] & /@ (And[#, True] & /@ regs)]
```

[image]

Replace `And[#, True] &` with `And[#, x >= 2 y] &` to get

[image]

Replace `And[#, True] &` with `And[#, x <= y] &` to get

[image]